# MySQL COUNT query takes too long

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm running a very simple MySQL query via workbench in order to count the number of entries in a table:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database.table`

There are approximately 3 million entries in the table but it is taking over 10 minutes to count the number of entries.  I could add extra processors and servers to the machine if that helps but at this point I am just trying to figure out why it takes so long to count three million rows.

Any ideas what I can do to get the query to run faster?

Comment: The output of `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database.table` could be helpful

Comment: If you have any index at all on a column from this table, do a count on the indexed column. E.g. `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM database.table`.

Comment: @Reto That took about 1 second. I didn't realize explain could be so helpful.  It's really strange as the MySQL website recommends count which is clearly terrible.  Can you put that as a solution so I can accept?

Comment: @Jethro Van Thuyne This will not help as MySQL COUNT is optimized and always does a COUNT(id) in the background..

Comment: @SeanJ `EXPLAIN` is not a solution - it's just a way to analyze what MySQL actually does ;)

Comment: @Reto EXPLAIN shows # id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  *rows*  Extra
I thought rows was actually the number of entries but just discovered, no it is not.

Comment: @SeanJ That is just the header - the second row would contain the actual values.. If everything is o.k. it should contain something like: `|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Select tables optimized away |`

Comment: @Reto you are correct, however it is a work server so I can't post the values, suffice to say the entries in one table are 1389954, whereas the rows are 1274557, (strange!).  I assume there must be a relationship but what it is I don't know. Also, it is taking 472 seconds to read 1,389,954 entries, not good!

Comment: @Ryan Vincent yes, that were my thoughts.

Comment: @SeanJ what fields does your table have?

Comment: @RyanVincent Reto I can state the following: select_type : simple, type : index, key : PRIMARY, key_len: 146, Extra : Using index.  Maybe the key_len is the problem?

Comment: @Reto table has two fields one is type 'varchar(48)' other is  'mediumblob'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 minutes is ridiculous for a table with only 3 million rows. I would expect it to take a few seconds at most. You must have a huge amount of other load on the same server, or else the server is underpowered.

This is one big weakness of the InnoDB storage engine: `SELECT COUNT(*)` isn't optimizable, because the number of rows in the table depends on your transaction's view of the table. So it has to visit every row and determine row-by-row whether your transaction can "see" that row. Therefore `SELECT COUNT(*)` seems to take a long time.

MyISAM is a bit better at this, because the table metadata keeps the current count of rows in the table, and the `SELECT COUNT(*)` optimizes for this, reading the total out of the metadata. However, this doesn't help if you do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE ...any conditions...` because it only keeps one total number of rows in the metadata, not subtotals for any conceivable condition.

If you need to optimize this, you could keep the total in another table yourself, increment it when you `INSERT` to your table, and decrement it when you `DELETE`.

Comment: Does `count(1)` differ from `count(*)` in this case?

Comment: No, In MySQL, there is no difference between `count(1)` and `count(*)`.

Comment: @BillKarwin MySQL is running on a dedicated Ubunutu server with 5 x E5649  @ 2.53GHz processors, so hardly underpowered and I've disabled most of the queues loading data....

Comment: Well I can't guess why it's taking 10 minutes without analyzing your system. That's such a huge difference from what it should take, that I suspect it's a locked table, or else the system is swapping.